# Algorithm Help for Directed Graph List

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I have an assignment for my class where we are attempting to find the best (cheapest) path to a destination. The description is as follows:

> Each tech has a name, a cost to buy that tech, a boolean saying whether or not the player has the tech already, and a list of 0 to N techs that are available for purchase when the player buys this tech. There are three categories of tech in Tactigo: Social, Military, and Science.  Each of the three starts with a basic tech that the player must purchase before purchasing more advanced techs.  These basic techs are special because they are always available for purchase.
> Looking at the diagram, you will note that a few techs are unlocked by multiple techs.  Remember that techs are unlocked as soon as ANY tech unlocks them.  In other words, you need either "Being Nice to Animals" OR "Being a Dick to People" in order to buy "Attack Animal Training".  You don't need both, just one. Your task is to find the cheapest way to get any given technology.  The player might own any set of techs already, so you must account for that.  For example, if the player already owns "Being Nice to People" and wants to find the cheapest way to get "Making Friends", the path returned should just be "Making Friends".  They don't need to purchase anything else.

The Graph looks as follows:

[image]

I originally thought of doing a depth-first-search on each of the 3 categories while calculating the cost of each path taken. My Code for this function is as follows:

```
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This function finds the best path to the tech we want.
//      * goalTech: The index of the tech we're looking for.  Call GetTechByIndex() to get the actual Tech instance.
//      * bestPath: The best path to the goal tech.  This is an array sorted in the order of the best path from the 
//                  start to the goal.  This is an output variable; it's what you need to populate with this function.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TechTree::FindBestPath(int goalTech, Path& bestPath)
{
    //First ensure that best path is cleared out
    bestPath.clear();

    //Get Tech Instance for this Goal Tech
    const Tech* pGoalTech = GetTechByIndex(goalTech);

    //make sure we get a valid tech
    assert(pGoalTech != nullptr);

    //Check first if user already has this unlocked. 
    if (pGoalTech->HasTech())
    {
        //just return
        return;
    }

    //Check if the goal tech is one of the three starting techs.
    if (pGoalTech == GetBasicSocialTech()|| pGoalTech == GetBasicScienceTech() || pGoalTech == GetBasicMilitaryTech())
    {

        //now we know that one of the basic techs are the goal, so we just add one of those to the path
        if (pGoalTech == GetBasicSocialTech())
            bestPath.push_back(GetBasicSocialTech());
        else if (pGoalTech == GetBasicMilitaryTech())
            bestPath.push_back(GetBasicMilitaryTech());
        else
            bestPath.push_back(GetBasicScienceTech());


        return; //now return
    }


    //my process will be as follows. 
    //1. Since all the edges are directed we need to traverse down three different graphs: Social (starting at index 0), Military (starting at index 4) and Science (starting at index 8)
    //2. I am going to perform a depth-first search starting at Social and then moving down to Military and then Science.
    //3. As I am performing a depth-first I am going to keep track of a path and its respective cost, if a search gets to the goal I will make sure to register that and then move onto the next graph.
    //4. When there are no more paths to search I send the lowest cost one back. 

    ///start with social at index 0
    const Tech* pStartSocialTech = GetBasicSocialTech();
    std::pair<int, std::vector<const Tech*>> bestCurrentPath;


    //get starting cost for this category before we move into neighbors,
    // if player already has this tech we set this to zero if not we get the cost of buying into this category
    int startingCost = pStartSocialTech->HasTech() ? 0 : pStartSocialTech->GetCost();


    

    /*pStartSocialNeighbors = get all neighbors for starting point at social

    while (destination is not found AND there are more neighbors to pStartSocialNeighbors)
    {
        DFS(neighbor, dest) //if this finds the destination we store a path and its cost, otherwise it doesnt do anything and we move on to next basic tree
    }

    //do the same thing for military and science...
    */
}
```

I have a lot of comments on it but I am just wondering if this is the best route to take. Other options are Dijkstras or A* but I don't know how you would traverse the path of this directed graph. I am not looking for a direct answer since this is a homework assignment but I am looking for some guidance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Going from the target to source using Dijkstras, you need to modify the stop condition if you want to stop before searching all paths. I don't see any heuristic for A* in this case.

- Adding a node with a path to all known techs

You can now use Dijkstras / Bellman-Ford.

Using A* has the problem you need to find a heuristic that works. You could use depth times min cost of all edges. that requires you to already have traversed the graph to assign depth.